# How to describe the J invariant in simple terms

Tags: soft-question, elliptic-curves

I'm giving a presentation in school and I want to describe the J invariant in a way that everyone will understand it, except I don't understand it well enough to be able to explain it in simple terms. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: School at what level? (It seems to me that you should perhaps pick a simpler topic if you want everyone to understand it...)

Comment: @HansLundmark It's not exactly for a math presentation. It's more of a philosophy presentation referencing math as an area of knowledge

Comment: So are you giving a talk only about the J invariant, or is it just something that comes up briefly in connection with something else? What level of detail do you have in mind? Does your audience know about complex numbers to begin with? Etc. It's hard to give a reasonable answer without a bit more context.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yeah it's something that comes up briefly in connection with something else. Most of my audience knows what complex numbers are, and the main thing they'll be looking forward to is a brief description of what the J Invariant is studied for (in the context of pure math that is)